# TexturePaint; where are all the options?

Tags: texture-painting

I downloaded the latest build of 2.8 yesterday. Now I face this problem and I merely require a solution.
[image]

On the picture you can see my current layout of Blender in TexturePaint-Mode. Over the Viewport is this bar with "View" and "Brush", and in all versions (2.79 as 2.8) were there options like creating a palette, jitter factor, ...

And I cant find these important options now.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the little wrench and screwdriver icon on the right side. Above the render settings in the Properties panel.